# Proving $\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{1}{n^3} \sin(nx)$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, continuity

$\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{1}{n^3} \sin(nx)$

to prove this, I'm trying to prove $\frac{1}{n^3} \sin(nx)$ is uniformly continuous.

So I let $y = x + \delta$ and did

$\frac{1}{n^3} \sin(nx + n\delta) - \frac{1}{n^3} \sin(nx) < \epsilon$

However I have no idea how to proceed the proof from here.

Comment: Using MVT prove that the function is, in fact, Lipschitz.

Comment: $\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{1}{n^3} \sin(nx)$
is continuous and periodic.

Comment: @zkutch $\epsilon$ is given. Your upper bound may be larger hence useless.

Comment: If I show $\frac{1}{n^3} \sin (nx)$ is lipschitz, will it be enough? Or should I show it uniformly converges? If so, how can I show it uniformly converges?

Comment: Duplicate: [continuous and Periodic function is Uniformly continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24818)

Comment: @zkutch indeed, and a useless $2$ then.

Comment: $\left|\frac{1}{n^3} \sin(nx + n\delta) - \frac{1}{n^3} \sin(nx)\right| =2\frac{1}{n^3}\left|\sin \frac{n\delta}{2}\cos\frac{2nx + n\delta}{2}  \right|\leqslant \frac{n\delta}{n^3}$

Comment: Can't I use dirichlet test? Isn't $\sum^\infty_{n=1}\sin(nx)$ bounded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, since $|\frac{1}{n^3}sin(nx)|\leq \frac{1}{n^3}$, by Weiertsrass M-test, the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}sin(nx)$converges absolutely and uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.

Second, for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\frac{1}{n^3}sin(nx)$ is continuous on $[0,2\pi]$. Therefore, the series itself is continuous(also uniformly continuous) on $[0,2\pi]$ due to uniformly convergence.

Last, it's clear that for all $n$, $2\pi$ is a period for $\frac{1}{n^3}sin(nx)$. Hence $2\pi$ is also a period for the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}sin(nx)$ (you can prove it by the definition of limit, which is easy). A continuous and periodic function on $\mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous.